# Associate a view controller to a new swift file

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

Can anyone help me in this? I have to open from my (app) mainMenu a new swift file via presentScene. Now, this file have to present a tableView and I do not quite figure out how to link this new file to his xib. Let's say that my file is named *newFile.swift*. I have created the *newFileViewController.xib*, selected in the inspector *Class: newFile*. What next? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your newFile you have to have a class declaration, this class has to be a subclass of UITableViewController as you want a tableView. This is done by doing :

```
class myTableViewController: UITableViewController {

}
```

Then I suggest reading a couple of tutorials to help you. We cannot create the program for you. Try these website for quality tutorials:

http://www.raywenderlich.com

http://www.appcoda.com